# Magento Object not found

Tags: php, magento, wamp

I have installed WAMP on my system.
A couple of days ago i was working on a magento site on localhost.
But now, whenever I install a fresh magento site on the localhost I get the following error

> Object not found!
>
> The requested URL was not found on this server. The link on the referring page seems to be wrong or outdated. Please inform the author of that page about the error.
>
> If you think this is a server error, please contact the webmaster.
>
> Error 404
>
> dev.ytcvn.com
> Apache/2.4.10 (Win32) OpenSSL/1.0.1i PHP/5.5.19

Comment: Create Virtual Hosts, one for each project. This makes each site seperate rather than sharing localhosts DocumentRoot folder. [This post should help you create Virtual Hosts](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23665064/project-links-do-not-work-on-wamp-server/23990618#23990618), its written for WAMPServer but you can pick the basic idea out of it and apply it to your environment.

Answer (score -1):

mod_rewrite is not enabled in your apache. Check for it.